# Why I can't see the value of binding in my datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I try to use with bindinig in Datagrid but it is not show me the values

that is my code :

in the xaml:

```
<Grid DataContext="ListFromFolderToFileTransferViewModel">
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid" SelectionChanged="selectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Folders,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserAddRows="False"   >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Folders" Binding="{Binding Source=Folders}" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="false" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

in the xaml.cs :

```
public ListFromFolderToFileTransferView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ListFromFolderToFileTransferViewModel();
    }
```

in the viewModel:

```
    object _lock = new object();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ObservableCollection<string> _Folders=new ObservableCollection<string>();;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Folders { get => _Folders; set { _Folders = value; OnPropertyChanged("Folders"); } }

    public ListFromFolderToFileTransferViewModel()
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Folders, _lock);                   
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(FilePath);
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            Folders.Add(d.Name);
        }
    }
```

and I see table taht in evry line its write for me **Folders** and dont show the values

someone can help me
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
<Grid DataContext="ListFromFolderToFileTransferViewModel">
```

assigns the string `"ListFromFolderToFileTransferViewModel"` to the DataContext of the Grid, which is then inherited by the DataGrid. That string does of course not have a `Folders` property.

The binding expression

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Folders,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

is wrong. You have to set the Binding's Path, not its Source, and setting its UpdateSourceTrigger is pointless because it is a OneWay Binding.

The expression

```
Binding="{Binding Source=Folders}"
```

on the DataGridTextColumn is also wrong, because a string item in the Folders collection does not have a Folders property, and again, Source is wrong.

Remove the DataContext assignment from the Grid, and use correct Binding expressions:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folders" Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

or - because you can omit `Path` in a Binding expression:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folders" Binding="{Binding}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```